# FFmpeg filter_complex merging two commands

Tags: ffmpeg, transpose

I'm having trouble merging these two commands, if anyone can help me merge the top ones transposing and watermarking to the second one I would really appreciate it.  I've tried a few things such as:

```
ffmpeg -i .\test1.flv -i .\test2.flv -loop 1 -i .\watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]transpose=1[a];[1]transpose=1[b];[a][b]hstack[c];[c][2]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5:shortest=1; [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" -c:v libx264 -f mp4 -threads 24 -y matt.mp4 

ffmpeg -i .\test1.flv -i .\test2.flv -loop 1 -i .\watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3;[0]transpose=1[a];[1]transpose=1[b];[a][b]hstack[c];[c][2]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5:shortest=1" -c:v libx264 -f mp4 -threads 24 -y matt.mp4
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intent right, this is what you want

```
ffmpeg -i .\test1.flv -i .\test2.flv -loop 1 -i .\watermark.png -filter_complex
        "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,transpose=1[a];
         [1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,transpose=1[b];
         [a][b]hstack[c];
         [c][2]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5:shortest=1[v];
         [0]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[x];[1]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[y];
         [x][y]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -f mp4 -threads 24 -y matt.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you !  Is there any way to sync the audio streams?  The second input video audio is two seconds behind or so on average.  I know of itoffset but not sure if I can rely on that - I'm having trouble finding other ways to keep it synced

Comment: Thanks Mulvya!  It worked fine.  I figured out the initial desync was actually caused due to memory running high towards the end of a long encode.